# Why my fileOutputstream ignores append "true" flag?

Tags: java, wrapper, fileoutputstream

I m trying to wrap FileinputStream and change close method of Parent in my wrapper class "Amigo". As u can see in code, i use default FileInputStream object to write some data in end of file in case of using .close() method. But, despite that i use "append" to "true" flag in the fileOutputStream field, my programm is still overwrites data in file. Why is this happens?

```
public class AmigoOutputStream extends FileOutputStream{
public static String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Егор\\IdeaProjects\\JavaRushTasks\\2.JavaCore\\src\\com\\javarush\\task\\task18\\task1813\\r.txt";
private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);
private static final String JAVA_RUSH = "JavaRush © All rights reserved.";


public AmigoOutputStream(FileOutputStream name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(String.valueOf(name),true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new AmigoOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)).close();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.write(JAVA_RUSH.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The line with `new FileOutputStream(fileName)` inside `main` will wipe the file and that runs before `new FileOutputStream(fileName,true)` which is inside the class.

You are also creating a new file which has an unusual name - set to `String.valueOf(name)`. You may want something like this which allows caller to specify the file and means `AmigoOutputStream` always sends extra bytes to some file:

```
public class AmigoOutputStream extends FileOutputStream{
    private static final String JAVA_RUSH = "JavaRush © All rights reserved.";

    public AmigoOutputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(name,true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(OutputStream os = new AmigoOutputStream("r.txt")) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        write(JAVA_RUSH.getBytes());
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the quick answer. i must use FileInputstream instead of String in AmigoClass constructor, thats a reson why i use .toString in the super(method)